# How do i add the "coloumns" button in my admin grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I've been trying to add the "Columns" button

[image] in my new custom grid UI component so that I can customize my view. Can someone tell me how it's done? I'm assuming it's a very generic function since its included in a lot of Magento out-of-the-box forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the `<listingtoolbar>` tag inside your List UI component

```
<columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
```